# How to Use session logs as a source and extract the session stats and load it to the DB

Tags: unix, informatica

I need to capture session level details in a table. i have 150 workflows for which i need to maintain an audit table which will have info like session start time, session end time, applied rows, rejected rows etc.

i can not use workflow variables using assignment task method because i need a reusable solution since i have 150 workflows.

i tried using Post Session Success Command Task with built in variables as $PM@TableName etc.
But there is no built in varible to capture the session start time and end time.

Last option i thought that could help is extract stats from session logs. can anyone please explain me how to achieve this.

Please let me know if there is any way to deal with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Here's the Framework to get this done:
   http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2014/01/an-etl-framework-for-operational.html
2. Each session hfas a $SessionName.StartTime as well as $SessionName.EndTime variable available
3. It's a terrible idea to try and parse the logs. Feasible, but I'd avoid it.
4. All information is already available in Informatica Repository. For every Workflow and every task of the Workflow. That should be used instead.